# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver on Mac OS X Attempting to use Derby

Tags: java, sql, exception, derby

I am getting a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver when I am trying to connect to a database with Java. I am on Mac OS 10.5 using the NetBeans IDE. It seems to be having trouble with the EmbeddedDriver, but I'm not sure what I am missing:

```
    public class A
    {
        Connection conn = null;

        public A(String URL, String username, String password) throws SQLException
        {       
                try
                {
                     Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
                }
                catch (SQLException sqlException)
                {
                    sqlException.printStackTrace();
                    invalidate();
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound)
                {
                    classNotFound.printStackTrace();
                    invalidate();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No suitable driver" usually means that the URL you've supplied to connect has incorrect syntax.  What is your URL?

The server version would have a host and port; I believe the embedded URL should be "jdbc:derby:flixnet", according to these docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

Comment: Then I get this:
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'flixnet' not found.

Comment: Then you do not have a flixnet database created.

Comment: I don't know if anyone is still watching this 3.5 year old question anymore, but you're quite correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver".
As i see you are accessing a derby server not an embedded database.

Answer (score 0):

It is declared as a constant here:

```
final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/flixnet";
```

Don't ask about the name... I got this URL by right-clicking the database in NetBeans and then going to Properties -> Database URL.

And I have added the derby.jar and derbyclient.jar files from /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-v3-prelude/javadb/lib/derby.jar and derbyclient.jar from the same directory.

Comment: The server version would have a host and port; I believe the embedded URL should be "jdbc:derby:flixnet", according to these docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the derbyclient.jar to the "Libraries" folder in your Netbeans project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try this:

1. Make sure you update your JDK and Netbeans to latest version
2. Right click your project's Libraries
3. Choosing "Add Library..."
4. Find and choose "Java DB Driver", then click "Add Library"

That's how I solved the problem, I hope this will help some new programmer like me:)
PS It will add "derbyclient.jar" for you